# expo-router@2: Custom options disrupt animation when navigating between same routes

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I'm encountering an issue with `expo-router@2` when using custom screen options. The problem arises when navigating between identical routes, e.g. from `/[id]` to `/[id]`.

Without custom screen options / With custom screen options

[image] [image]

/app/index.js

```
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => router.push({
          pathname: "/[id]",
          params: { id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) },
        })}
      >
        <Text>Go inside</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

/app/[id].js

```
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => router.push({
          pathname: "/[id]",
          params: { id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) },
        })}
      >
        <Text>Go deeper</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>{id}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

/app/_layout.js:

```
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      {/* if you uncomment following tag it will break the default behavior: */}
      {/* <Stack.Screen
        name="[id]"
        options={{
          title: "title",
        }}
      /> */}
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

**Reproduction**: I can't create Expo Snack, because it only allows to create a Snack for SDK<=48, but expo-router@2 is only available in SDK 49, so I put a minimal reproducible example in this [repository](https://github.com/ozio/expo-router-bug).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you figure this out? It's happening to me now

Comment: @deathandtaxes yes! use `getId` prop on Screen, it should be different to make it a new item in a stack. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen#getid